# Installing GDAL with HDF4 driver on Debian system

Tags: gdal, linux, hdf, spyder

I am working on a Debian 7 Wheezy system using Anaconda and working from Spyder.  I've had a hard time installing a version of GDAL that reads HDF4 drivers.  Could someone walk me through the installation process?

Comment: Have you [tried this approach](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110929/1872)?

Comment: I have.  I uninstalled GDAL, reinstalled using jakebrinkmann's comments.  When I try to read a HDF file `data = gdal.Open(hdffilename)` I get the error: 'hdffilename not recognised as supported file format"

Comment: Did you adress the subdataset in `hdffilename`? HDFs usually consist of multiple subdatasets. GDAL is able to open the subdatasets but not the HDF "container" as a whole. If you can provide an example file we might be able to determine if that's causing your issue.

Comment: I found that [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188587/modis-data-with-hdf-extension-not-compiling-in-ubuntu/189447#189447) suggested by @Soumya worked in my particular case. Maybe you could try it out?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in ubuntu, I did not use anaconda though, just used the ubuntu version of python  and my solution is here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/148441